# A small step in Christoffel symbol

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The Christoffel symbol is defined as $$\Gamma_{ij}^k=\frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^j}+\frac{\partial g_{lj}}{\partial x^i}-\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^l})\tag1$$

Now in the expression about the divergence operator in local coodinates, the Christoffel symbol is expressed as $$\Gamma_{ki}^i=\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}=\frac{1}{2G}\frac{\partial G}{\partial x^k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt G}\frac{\partial \sqrt G}{\partial x^k}\tag2$$ where $G=det(g_{ij})$.

For the above formula, I understand the first equality since it is the direct apllication of $(1)$, but I can't understand the second and the third with the introduction of $G=det(g_{ij})$.

Can someone explain to me? Appreciate your feedback, thanks!

Comment: it's definitely not an obvious formula (not for me anyways) Try calculating from the RHS. You'll need to know how to differentiate a determinant function. Jacobi's formula might come in handy (I think that's the name of the formula). Btw there's also several questions like this one on the Physics page, so you should look there as well

Comment: Proven [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309535/a-helpful-proof-in-contracting-the-christoffel-symbol).